# D3 sunburst second tier doesn't occupy full width of first tier

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a D3 sunburst plot, with the inner layer the first categories, and outer layer the subcategories of the first categories. For example in my data, I want to show that out of all samples, there are 67% unverified and 33% verified, and out of the verified category 51% of those are illegal and 49% are not, and out of the unverified category, 36% of those are low risk, 20% mid and 44% high risk. I expected the second layer to occupy the full width of the category they belong to in the first layer, but it is not the case, I get the following instead.

[image]

Here is my code, could someone maybe point me in the right direction of how to get the results I am looking for? Thank you.

```js
var nodeData = {
  "name": "CATEGORY",
  "children": [{
    "name": "verified",
    "size": 33,
    "children": [{
      "name": "illegal",
      "size": 51
    }, {
      "name": "legal",
      "size": 49
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "unverified",
    "size": 67,
    "children": [{
      "name": "low risk",
      "size": 36
    }, {
      "name": "mid risk",
      "size": 20
    }, {
      "name": "high risk",
      "size": 44
    }]
  }]
};

var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
var g = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

var partition = d3.partition()
  .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

var root = d3.hierarchy(nodeData)
  .sum(function(d) {
    return d.size
  });

partition(root);
var arc = d3.arc()
  .startAngle(function(d) {
    return d.x0
  })
  .endAngle(function(d) {
    return d.x1
  })
  .innerRadius(function(d) {
    return d.y0
  })
  .outerRadius(function(d) {
    return d.y1
  });


g.selectAll('path')
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr("display", function(d) {
    return d.depth ? null : "none";
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style('stroke', '#fff')
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer, which I deleted, because I read your question too fast. Looking more carefully the problem is just the structure of your data: you set the `size` of the children, but you also have a (different) `size` for the parents. The `hierarchy.sum()` sets the value of the parent depending on the values of the children. You have to change your data structure, or, alternatively, create your own layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have size only for the children. Total children sum should be equal 100.

```
var nodeData = {"name": "CATEGORY","children": [{
"name": "verified",
"children": [{
  "name": "illegal",
  "size": 33 * (51/100)
}, {
  "name": "legal",
  "size": 33 * (49/100) }]}, {
"name": "unverified",
"children": [{
  "name": "low risk",
  "size": 67 * (36/100)}, {
  "name": "mid risk",
  "size": 67 * (20/100)}, {
  "name": "high risk",
  "size": 67 * (44/100)}] }]};
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/gxwk9hnh/)